# Why does dumping and loading a Hash using Marshal in Ruby throw a FormatError?

Tags: ruby, marshalling

I'm running Ruby installed from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/). Here's the version:

```
C:\Users\Sathya>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
```

Here's the exact code, which is throwing the error:

```
hashtime = Hash.new(Time.mktime('1970'))
hashtime[1]  = Time.now
=> 2011-10-04 19:26:53 +0530
print hashtime
{1=>2011-10-04 19:26:53 +0530}=> nil
hashtime[1]  = Time.now
=> 2011-10-04 19:27:20 +0530
print hashtime
{1=>2011-10-04 19:27:20 +0530}=> nil
File.open('timehash','w') do |f|
  f.write Marshal.dump(hashtime)
end
=> 56
```

Now, trying to load it.

```
Marshal.load (File.read('timehash'))
```

Gives the error:

```
ArgumentError: dump format error for symbol(0x42)
        from (irb):10:in `load'
        from (irb):10
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Why is this throwing an error? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

I'm running on Windows 7 Ultimate, 64-bit

---

Here's the results from the edited debug code you had mentioned:

```
hashtime = Hash.new
=> {}
hashtime[1] = Time.now
=> 2011-10-04 20:49:52 +0530
hashdump = Marshal.dump(hashtime)
=> "\x04\b{\x06i\x06Iu:\tTime\r\x8F\xE4\e\x80<\xADGO\x06:\voffseti\x02XM"
hashtime = Marshal.load (hashdump)
=> {1=>2011-10-04 20:49:52 +0530}
print hashtime
{1=>2011-10-04 20:49:52 +0530}=> nil
```

---

Results to Edit 2:

```
hashtime = Hash.new
=> {}
hashtime[1] = Time.now
=> 2011-10-04 21:04:24 +0530
hashdump = Marshal.dump(hashtime)
=> "\x04\b{\x06i\x06Iu:\tTime\r\x8F\xE4\e\x80\x92o\x8C\x89\x06:\voffseti\x02XM"
print "hashdump: #{hashdump}"
ÅS?ÇÆoîë?:?offseti?XM=> nile
File.open('timehash','w') do |f|
 f.write hashdump
end
=> 36
hashdump2 = File.read('timehash')
=> "\x04\b{\x06i\x06Iu:\tTime\n\x8F\xE4\e\x80\x92o\x8C\x89\x06:\voffseti\x02XM"
print "hashdump2: #{hashdump2}"
hashdump2:{?i?Iu:       Time
ÅS?ÇÆoîë?:?offseti?XM=> nil
hashtime2 = Marshal.load (hashdump2)
ArgumentError: dump format error for symbol(0x8c)
        from (irb):73:in `load'
        from (irb):73
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Some of the characters didn't come out, here's a screenshot:

[image: hash-dump-marshal]

---

Now I'm getting a time format different error

```
hashtime = Hash.new
=> {}
hashtime[1] = Time.now
=> 2011-10-04 21:23:15 +0530
hashdump = Marshal.dump(hashtime)
=> "\x04\b{\x06i\x06Iu:\tTime\r\x8F\xE4\e\x80\xB9\xE1\xFB\xD4\x06:\voffseti\x02X
M"
print "hashdump: #{hashdump}"
ÅΣ←Ç╣ß√╘♠:♂offseti☻XM=> nile
File.open('timehash','wb') do |f|
 f.write hashdump
end
=> 36
hashdump2 = File.read('timehash')
=> "\x04\b{\x06i\x06Iu:\tTime\n\x8F\xE4\e\x80\xB9\xE1\xFB\xD4\x06:\voffseti\x02X
M"
print "hashdump2: #{hashdump2}"
hashdump2:{♠i♠Iu:       Time
ÅΣ←Ç╣ß√╘♠:♂offseti☻XM=> nil
hashtime2 = Marshal.load (hashdump2)
TypeError: marshaled time format differ
        from (irb):10:in `_load'
        from (irb):10:in `load'
        from (irb):10
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Comment: If dumping to a filestream is allowed, see what happens if you write to a stringio object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combination of the 2 answers from @Josh and @derp work for me. Here is the code (written to a file):

```
hashtime = Hash.new(Time.mktime('1970'))
hashtime[1]  = Time.now
File.open('timehash','wb') do |f|
  f.write Marshal.dump(hashtime)
end
newhash = Marshal.load (File.binread('timehash'))
p newhash
p newhash.default
```

Results in the following output:

```
c:\apps\ruby>ruby h.rb
{1=>2011-10-05 08:09:43 +0200}
1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0100
```

Comment: Indeed, should have mentioned that I tested writing with `'wb'` as well.

Comment: All 3 worked, but I'll accept this since this is a curated answer, with best parts of all. Thanks @mlie!

Answer (score 13):

You need to write to the file in binary mode by appending a `b` to the file mode:

```
File.open('timehash','wb') do |f|
  f.write Marshal.dump(hashtime)
end
```

You can see this is the issue by comparing the strings (from our debugging) before writing to disk vs after reading back in:

```
=> "\x04\b{\x06i\x06Iu:\tTime\r\x8F\xE4\e\x80\x92o\x8C\x89\x06:\voffseti\x02XM"
=> "\x04\b{\x06i\x06Iu:\tTime\n\x8F\xE4\e\x80\x92o\x8C\x89\x06:\voffseti\x02XM"
                             ^^
```

a `\r` (carriage return) is being changed to a `\n` (newline)

However, it seems like even with the binary modifier your system is not obeying you and is changing `\r` to `\n`... So let's try encoding the data to base64:

```
File.open('timehash','w') do |f|
  hashtime_marshal = Marshal.dump(hashtime)
  f.write [hashtime_marshal].pack("m")
end

hashtime_encoded = File.read('timehash')
hashtime = Marshal.load( hashtime_encoded.unpack("m")[0] )
```

Let me know if that works?

---

**Old Information:**

Don't pass anything to `Hash.new`:

```
>> hashtime = Hash.new
=> {}
>> hashtime[1] = Time.now
=> Tue Oct 04 10:57:49 -0400 2011
>> hashtime
=> {1=>Tue Oct 04 10:57:49 -0400 2011}
>> File.open('timehash','w') do |f|
?>   f.write Marshal.dump(hashtime)
>> end
=> 22
>> Marshal.load (File.read('timehash'))
(irb):10: warning: don't put space before argument parentheses
=> {1=>Tue Oct 04 10:57:49 -0400 2011}
```

The documentation states that the `obj` parameter to `Hash.new` is the default value... it *should* work as you have it... I don't know why it doesn't... but in your case `nil` is an acceptable default, just check to see if values are `nil` and if so, use a `Time.mktime('1970')` for them instead.

**EDIT:** That solved the problem for me, however, I'm on OS X not Windows. So, let's try a bit of debugging. What happens when you run the following code?

```
hashtime = Hash.new
hashtime[1] = Time.now
hashdump = Marshal.dump(hashtime)
hashtime = Marshal.load (hashdump)
print hashtime
```

**EDIT #2:** OK. So `Marshal.dump` and `Marshal.load` seem to work. Looks like it's something with the file I/O... Please post the results of the following code...

```
hashtime = Hash.new
hashtime[1] = Time.now
hashdump = Marshal.dump(hashtime)
print "hashdump: #{hashdump}"
File.open('timehash','w') do |f|
  f.write hashdump
end
hashdump2 = File.read('timehash')
print "hashdump2: #{hashdump2}"
hashtime2 = Marshal.load (hashdump2)
print hashtime2
```

Comment: OK Sathya I think I have it now!

Comment: I tried wb + no params to Hash, now I'm getting a time format differ error

Comment: This seems to be coming on the WIndows build, I just checked the same code in my Linux VM (1.8.7 & 1.9.2-p0) and no errors @Josh

Comment: @Sathya okay -- I'm going to look for some other solutions for you -- please stand by!

Comment: @Sathya please try base64 encoding the data, let's see if that solves the issue. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of reading with `File.read` try `File.binread` or `File.open('timehash', 'rb')`

Comment: I'm glad you solved your issue. I was able to learn about Marshal as well.